# Proving/disproving $\{a^{k_1}\}=\{a^{k_2}\}=\{a^{k_3}\}$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. Prove or disprove that there do not exist three distinct $k_1, k_2, k_3\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{a^{k_1}\}=\{a^{k_2}\}=\{a^{k_3}\}\neq 0$, where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: $\{\sqrt{2}^2\} = \{\sqrt{2}^4\} = \{\sqrt{2}^6\} = 0$ ??

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: It's a my conjecture. I should have said that.

Comment: Perhaps a more useful reformulation: If $a\in\mathbb R$ is a solution of $x^{k_2}-x^{k_1}=m$ and $x^{k_3}-x^{k_2}=n$ for positive integers $k_1<k_2<k_3$ and $m,n$, then $a$ is integer. I.e. a nontrivial algebraic integer cannot be a root of two different polynomials of the form $x^{k}-x^l-m$.

Comment: Nice problem! If it's a conjecture, you should write "prove or disprove that".

Comment: Certainly there are values of $a$ where there are no $k$'s.  For example, $a=\sqrt 2$.  If we had $\{2^{k_1/2}\}=\{2^{k_2/2}\} \neq 0$ we would have a rational expression for $\sqrt 2$.  I think you want to ask if there is any $a$ where this is true.

Comment: Not an answer, but a closely related example: the plastic constant $P$ satisfies $\{P\}=\{P^3\}\neq 0$ and $\{P^4\}=\{P^5\}\neq 0$.

Comment: And of course if you allow $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead, you have $\{\phi^{-1}\}=\{\phi\}=\{\phi^2\}\neq 0$ and a related triplet for $P$.

Comment: @barto: The statement "a nontrivial algebraic integer cannot be a root of two different polynomials of the form $x^k-x^l-m$" is certainly false, as $P$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, we need one polynomial's $l$ to be equal to the $k$ of the other.

Comment: When polynomials $x^{k_2} −x^{k_1}−m$ and $x^{k_3} −x^{k_2}−n$ are not coprime or, at least, reducible?

Comment: I was looking at the polynomial formulation and trying to use Euclid's algorithm, but the presence of the 'mod 1' constants makes it (un)surprisingly tricky to actually get anywhere with that tactic.

Comment: special case : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363800/proving-that-x-is-an-integer-if-the-differences-between-any-two-of-x1919

Answer (score 6):

This is not a complete answer, but I thought the approach might help someone find a solution.  We can ask when the following condition holds for positive integers $a>b>c$ and $a>d\ge c$:
$$
x^a - x^d - m = P(x)(x^b - x^c - n),
$$
where $P(x)$ is some polynomial over $x$, and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  If it does, then $\{x^a\}=\{x^d\}$ and $\{x^b\}=\{x^c\}$ whenever $x$ is a root of $x^b-x^c-n$.  If, moreover, $d=b$ and the right-hand trinomial has a root in $\mathbb{R}$ for which $x^a\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, then OP's question has a positive answer.

Clearly $P(x)$ must start with $x^{a-b}$; so
$$
x^a-x^d-m=(x^b - x^c - n)(x^{a-b}+Q(x))=x^a-x^{a-b+c}-nx^{a-b}+Q(x)(x^b-x^c-n),
$$
or
$$
Q(x)(x^b-x^c-n)=x^{a-b+c}+nx^{a-b}-x^d-m.
$$
The constant term on the left and right must be $-m$, so $Q(x)=m/n+xR(x)$, giving
$$
(xR(x)+m/n)(x^b-x^c-n)=xR(x)(x^{b}-x^{c}-n)+(m/n)x^b-(m/n)x^c-m \\ =x^{a-b+c}+nx^{a-b}-x^d-m,
$$
or
$$
R(x)(x^b-x^c-n)=x^{a-b+c-1}+nx^{a-b-1}-x^{d-1}-(m/n)x^{b-1}+(m/n)x^{c-1}.
$$
We must have $c=1$ at this point, so
$$
R(x)(x^b-x-n)=x^{a-b}+nx^{a-b-1}-x^{d-1}-(m/n)x^{b-1}+(m/n).
$$
Now, for the highest-order terms to match, we need either $a-b \ge b$ or $d=b+1$.  The latter case does not help with OP's question, but setting $d=b+1$ gives $R(x)=-1$ and
$$
-x-n=-x^{a-b}-nx^{a-b-1}+(m/n)x^{b-1}-(m/n),
$$
so $m=n=1$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(5,3,1,4)$.  This gives the known but nontrivial result that $x^5-x^4-1=P(x)(x^3-x-1)$; and $x^3-x-1$ has as a real root the [plastic constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlasticConstant.html) $P=1.3247…$.  We conclude that $\{P^5\}=\{P^4\}$ and $\{P^3\}=\{P\}$, which is interesting but not exactly what we want.

If we instead set $a=2b+k$ for $k\ge 0$, then
$$
R(x)(x^b-x-n)=x^{b+k}+nx^{b+k-1}-x^{d-1}-(m/n)x^{b-1}+(m/n).
$$
Restricting ourselves to $d=b$,
$$
R(x)(x^b-x-n)=x^{b+k}+nx^{b+k-1}-\left(\frac{m}{n}+1\right)x^{b-1}+\left(\frac{m}{n}\right).
$$
It's then possible to try various values for $k$.  Interestingly, if $k=1$, then the solution $(a,b,c,d)=(5,2,1,2)$, $m=18$, $n=-3$ arises.  This corresponds to
$$
x^5-x^2-18 = P(x)(x^2-x+3),
$$
which is *very close* to a positive result.  Unfortunately $x^2-x+3$ has only complex roots: $r=1/2 + i\sqrt{11}/2$ and its complex conjugate.  But indeed
$$
r^5 = 31/2 + i\sqrt{11}/2, \\
r^2 = -5/2 + i\sqrt{11}/2, \\
r = 1/2 + i\sqrt{11}/2,
$$
so this can be seen as a complex solution to $\{x^5\}=\{x^2\}=\{x\}\neq 0$.

Comment: Just noticed that this answer was the 1,000,000th post on MSE. :-)

Comment: I also just noticed this @Marnix. Very good post for the milestone!